# How to fix neck crease in my model?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I can't seem to figure out how to fix the neck crease seen in the below image, can anyone help with this issue? I am pretty new to blender just started trying to work with it two days ago so not everything is clicking for me yet. The V shaped creases are accurate, but the circular crease where the neck connects to the body shouldn't be there.

Comment: People would need a lot more info to be able to reliably help.  This info would be best provided with a file.  (They need to figure out if the seams is due to texturing, perhaps normal map, or custom normals, or base normals, or, maybe, other things.)